# Are serial down-voters warned?

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I know that the system ultimately reverses serial down-voting but does it (or a moderator, though it would seem to be a truckload of work) send a warning?

Comment: Yes, a moderator dressed in a Sailor Moon costume delivers a warning in person to the tune of "Die Moritat von Mackie Messer" (probably known to many as "Mack the Knife").

Comment: There's only one way to know: I'm going to downvote all of your meta posts and see what happens when the reversal kicks in!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, serial voters are not warned.

Only if the voter down-voted answers and lost reputation (-1 per answer down voted) would they see a 'serial voting reversed' entry in their reputation log as the voters are undone.

The system assumes good faith here, and doesn't go out of their way to warn serial voters. Plenty of people go around discovering low-quality user accounts and start down voting posts by one user as they go through the profile, thinking they are helping out the site, for example. Or they really want to thank someone who helped them and serially up-vote a bunch of other answers.

On the other hand, a warning won't stop the genuinely malicious users; they'd just ignore the warning and try to find ways to *not* get the warning. Automated feedback on wether or not their serial vote is going undetected is not something we want here.

Moderators have the tools to detect voting fraud; any genuinely malicious voters will be dealt with. The rest don't do any actual harm here, but sending them a notice (warning, reminder, whatever) would serve little. People that serially vote in good faith do so just once or twice, so why worry those people?

Comment: So there is no automatism even if a users keeps doing it (testing the limits of the reversal script)?

Comment: It seems to me that assuming good faith is not mutually exclusive with... hmm... notifying a user. (I'm purposely not using the word "warning" as it has negative connotations.) I'd like to know if what I thought was useful to the site turned out to be seen as harmful.

Comment: @juergend: Moderators have other means of detecting voting fraud and will come talk to such repeat offenders. Why warn them that the long arm of the law is coming to look at what they should be perfectly aware of is unacceptable behaviour?

Comment: *Moderators have other means of detecting voting fraud* That is what I wanted to hear.

Comment: @Louis: Those with good intentions will be mortified and ashamed, while their actions did not actively harm anything. Those with bad intentions can use the information to their advantage.

Comment: I would say that the system assumes bad faith here. If it assumed good faith, it would explain to the user that they did something that was rejected. Instead, the system tries to bury the incident, which is the right thing if the serial votes were done with intent to commit some sort of fraud (either in the heat of the moment, in which case burying lets sleeping dogs lie, or in a sustained way, in which case burying makes it harder to test the limits of the detection system).

Comment: +1 "Automated feedback on wether or not their serial vote is going undetected is not something we want here."

Comment: "Automated feedback" but the "serial voting reversed" in the reputation history is exactly that...

Comment: Is there any special code that detects that I've legitimately upvoted a bunch of questions by, say, Martijn Pieters because he wrote 30 excellent answers in 5 minutes? :)

Comment: @abarnert I believe that would still be serial voting. Your motivation does not come into play. If you cast votes on a series of posts by the same user, it's serial voting. Even if the posts are all excellent, and deserve upvotes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi abarnert was joking. Besides, rate limiting prevents me from posting that many answers in that timeframe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, the specific example was obviously fictional. But I don't think it's always clear to everybody that any kind of serial voting on posts of the same user is not accepted, even if it's based on the merits of the posts.

Comment: _The system assumes good faith here_ : With so many incidents of, and so many questions about, serial down-voting, and no requirement for explaining down-votes, IMO indications are that _assuming good faith_ is **not** such a great policy, although I'm not sure I could come up with anything better.

Comment: @Vector: there are a **lot** of users on Stack Overflow, and percentage wise serial voting makes up a very very small fraction of voting patterns. Rest assured that moderators can handle the exceptions here, and *if* there is bad faith detected we [won't hesitate to deal with that behaviour](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291329/a-funny-case-of-bounty-retaliation/291336#291336)

Answer (score 21):

In general, for system-detected serial down-voting, we don't warn (as Martijn states). The system takes care of this, and we aren't notified that it has done so.

However, if this serial voting is strong enough that it comes to our attention and is clearly targeted in a malicious fashion at someone else, we will warn users directly about this. We even have a standard template for a moderator message that expresses why targeted down-voting is not tolerated here and why these votes will be invalidated.

It's a judgment call for when we feel the need to step in and warn someone, but this usually happens if there are repeated incidents of targeting a specific user or one extreme case of this happening.