# A funny case of bounty retaliation

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

Me and my colleague are both being targeted with serial down-voting. It has started soon after I put a bounty on [my colleague's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29638148/1768303).

The down-votes are being automatically reversed by the system; apparently, this doesn't stop the down-voter who seems to be very upset (and any motive I can think of makes me smile :)

I wonder though, is there any potential moderation consequences for the person engaged in this activity, besides the automatic reversal of votes?

Comment: He'll be detected and if he's downviting you for a while, for no reason, a moderator will send him a warning.

Comment: It is kinda obvious who did this, a moderator will surely send him a stern warning, throw him in the slammer if he keeps it up.  If no moderator responds here then alert one by flagging the question with a custom flag.

Comment: @Noseratio, Weird, why would anyone downvote you randomly due to a bounty?

Comment: Gotta love the [new account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4833177/) he created so he could [continue to post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29872063/157247). Serial downvoting or not, you have to give the guy credit (as you did in your comments on the deleted answer) for really, really trying to answer the question...

Comment: @Pacerier, I can only guess he might have been doing it in anger that he put a lot of efforts into his answer, with many editions, but we decided that another answer fits the question better.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I'd be glad to to reward his efforts with another bounty, just for the sake of it, but not to the new account he created. I think he should wait until suspension is lifted, then undelete and edit his original answer.

Comment: @Noseratio: Well, yeah. :-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The user was warned by a moderator shortly after the first occurrence of the votes was reversed — but it seems they have chosen to respond *to* the warning by continuing with their votes, resulting in your post on meta today. The user is now suspended. Any votes that remain will be reversed in due time.

Comment: I think 7 days is not enough. 2 months maybe is, not sure.
Scums like him will just learn how to trick the system next time. (not difficult to find out with 5 minutes of research)

Comment: @gdoron: For likely repeat offenders, I prefer to think of it as icing on the cake.

Comment: I must admit that you guys are doing a great job.