# How to politely get users frequently asking basic/related questions to slow down and do better research?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, etiquette

Last month I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854761/how-to-link-shared-lib-on-windows-visual-studio-2014) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043144/why-dll-file-gets-opened-while-copying-it-using-cmake) case of questions in the less popular [cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake) tag where the user was asked - more or less politely - to slow down with the frequency of their questions and invest more time in researching (or exercise more patience with their previous questions). The comments in both cases where - more or less politely - ignored (or even taken as offense).

I was hoping to find a polite solution without the need to bother a moderator. So far I have seen the following advises:

1. Flag e.g. as "Duplicate" or "Too broad"

   [How to deal with questions that ask about complete basics?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274645/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-ask-about-complete-basics)
2. Leave a comment and down-vote

   [How can other users warn a new user, frequently missing the SO policies for 'How to ask here?'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272866/how-can-other-users-warn-a-new-user-frequently-missing-the-so-policies-for-how)

I tried the first one on several questions in the past, but I never got enough votes to close it (maybe it's just me or not enough people came by). And I don't think the user asking it even sees that there are close votes.

I prefer the second, but I tend to not directly down-vote. The user should have a chance to improve the question. But the problem about this is, that in the cases above I more or less would have done something like a late "serial down-voting" which also seems unfair and [is even banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276492/are-serial-down-voters-warned).

But e.g. [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) suggests down-voting is the best option after all. And taking the "Needs to demonstrate research" part from [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) I just discovered doing my research before asking this question.

So I'm still hoping for a third solution.

Comment: Tell them to RTFM / LMGTFY... Oh, politely? No idea.

Comment: downvote them without leaving a mean comment. they'll be forced to wait longer and longer between each question posted until they start posting better quality ones. downvotes aren't mean, and by avoiding using them you're not giving the system the signal it needs to operate properly.

Comment: Downvote only the stuff that really deserves it to not get wrongfully tagged as a fraud. If enough people do it, the system will automagically do the third solution.

Comment: You have no real options in a small tag like that.  It will never be closed, and such a user will neither use nor appreciate your advice.  Downvote is all you can do, fingers crossed or a little prayer might help to ward off the rep hunters.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I'll keep it in mind. And maybe the close votes limit for small tags should be decreased or at least they should not age away so fast. I'll have to take a look into ["Why are 5 close votes required?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261746/why-are-5-close-votes-required) and ["Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

Comment: @KevinB Yes, down-voting seems to be the best option. Also the only one that gives the system and the OP direct feedback. I would still want to leave a comment to let the OP and also other users (e.g. possible reviewers) know why it was down-voted.